# Conversion of const char** to std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c#, c++, interop, type-conversion

I have the following wrapper to expose my C++ code to C#

```
extern "C" {
   LIBRARY_API void GenerateTables(
      const char* version, 
      const char* baseDir, 
      const char** fileList);
} // end extern "C"

void GenerateTables(
   const char* version,
   const char* baseDir,
   const char** fileList)
{
   std::string strVersion(version);
   std::string strBaseDir(baseDir);

   // I now need to convert my const char** to std::vector<std::string> 
   // so it can be passed to another internal method.
}
```

How can I convert my `const char** fileList` to `std:vector<std::string>`. I am relatively new to C++ and there is a clear problem with memory allocation here. I could do something like

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length() /* length() of what!? */; i++)
    vec.push_back(/* what!? */);
```

How can I do the required conversion and is there a better way of passing in an array of strings (`string[]`) from C# to C++ via interop?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Should we assume the list is terminated by a NULL pointer?

Comment: There needs to be some protocol for determining the length of the array. What is it?

Comment: I was hoping to make the number of strings in the `fileList` variable. So having in C# `List<string> fileList = new List<string> { /* some list */ };` and then using `ToArray()` before passing the array to the interop method. Like I said, I have not done this before so am open to other methods (if there are any). It is possible to get the `fileList` using a directory as they are all contained in a single folder, so I could pass in another `const char*` which holds a directory path which in turn is used to get the required file paths?

Comment: It's fine for the array to have a length that can vary. But the function needs to know that length. If not, how can it iterate over the array? It's easiest to pass the length as an extra parameter, if doing interop from C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the unmanaged code some way to obtain the length. There are two commonly used approaches:

1. Pass the length of the array as an extra parameter.
2. Use a null terminated array. The array ends when you encounter an item that is null.

Either option is simple enough for you to implement. The choice is entirely down to your personal preference.

If you choose the first option then you can populate the vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> files(fileList, fileList + length);
```

If you choose the second option then you'd use a loop like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> files;
const char** filePtr = fileList;
while (*filePtr != nullptr)
    files.push_back(*filePtr++);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the length of `fileList` array. Once you know it you can convert `fileList` using

```
size_t length = ... ;
std::vector<std::string> files( fileList, fileList + length );
```